# Sequential Consistency in Web Assembly

Tags: parallel-processing, webassembly

The [document](https://github.com/WebAssembly/threads/blob/master/proposals/threads/Overview.md) describing WebAssembly threads says:

> Atomic load/store memory accesses behave like their non-atomic counterparts, with the exception that the ordering of accesses is sequentially consistent.

This is in reference to `i32.atomic.load` versus `i32.load`, `i32.atomic.store` versus `i32.store`, etc.

What does it mean that the non-atomic operations aren't sequentially consistent? In what situations would the non-atomic operations not be suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory consistency of atomic operation define (the minimum requirement of) how atomic accesses are sequenced by the processor in relation to other variable. This is related to *memory barrier*. A relaxed atomic operation cause the atomic operation to be sequenced independently of other variables. This means that if you do:

```
non_atomic_variable = 42;
atomic_increment(atomic_variable);
```

Then, other threads may not see the updated value of `non_atomic_variable` when `atomic_variable` has been increased by the current thread. This is not possible in a sequentially consistent memory ordering because the compiler should use instructions so that there is a memory barrier forcing other threads to see the updated value when the increase is done and the atomic operation (eg. read) is sequenced from other threads.

A sequentially consistent memory ordering is safe but also slow. A relaxed memory ordering is fast because of weaker synchronizations (and more room for processors optimizations during load/stores). For example, with a relaxed memory ordering, a processor can execute the `non_atomic_variable` later because of a cache miss (thanks to an *out-of-order* execution). With a sequentially consistent memory ordering, the increment need to wait for the store to be done which can take some time when there is a cache miss.

Note that the memory ordering of the processor can be stronger than the one required by the software stack (eg. x86-64 processor have a strong memory ordering).

Comment: Thanks! To make sure I understand correctly, this is not an issue in a single thread because no further instructions will be executed until the load/store is complete. But in multithreading, one thread might attempt a load/store while another load/store is still in process. If Thread A is running `i32.atomic.store`, B tries to run `i32.atomic.load`, and C tries to run `i32.load`, B will lock until A is done, but C will immediately load whatever is there. If C tries to run `i32.store` while A is still running `i32.atomic.store`, the value C stores might get overwritten by the value stored by A.

Comment: Yeah in single thread all accesses are always sequentially consistent. The processor can reorder instructions but it will not have visible side effects (at least unless you try to do things like side-channel attack). For your multi-threaded use-case, C should not load a value modified by another thread. This cause an undefined behavior due to a race condition. The result is implementation-dependent. In practice, the load of C can be reordered or possibly even optimized out by the software stack.

Comment: Regarding A and B, if the A store is *sequenced* before the load of B, then yes, B typically waits for the cache line to be unlocked on most architecture. Processors can execute other instruction during this waiting time though. From the WebAssembly PoV, these instruction are just atomic so they cannot be interrupted by another one.

Comment: Regarding the C store, it is also an undefined behavior (race condition). Whether the value of C or A is kept is implementation defined so yes, the value of A can be overwritten because the processor can execute the store of C after the atomic store of A. In fact, AFAIK, basic load/store can be done in multiple parts (eg. 32-bit + 32-bit for a 64-bit store/load) so the value can be neither the one of C nor the one of A. Such a problem never happen with only atomic operations.